# How to show that when $X \subseteq A \land B \subseteq A$. if $X \cap B = \emptyset$ then $B \subseteq A \setminus X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When $B\subseteq A$ there is a set defined as $P(A:B)=\{X \in \mathscr P(A)\vert B \subseteq A \setminus X\}$. it is said that this set is equal to the set $\mathscr P(A\setminus B)$.
I can imagine how these two would be equal but I miss some steps through the proof;
$$
\forall X \in \mathscr P(A \setminus B)\iff X \subseteq A\setminus B \iff ? 
$$
I can also intuitively see that $P(A:B) \cap B = \emptyset$ but cannot proof it either. I think If I could prove this I can conclude the needed conclusion.

Comment: Your title line is very hard to parse.

Comment: Your displayed formula does not parse. You have a quantifier, "for all $X$ in the power set of $A\setminus B$", but no formula related to this quantified $X$; then you have an "if and only if", but the left hand side of that "if and only if" is not a well-formed formula: it is currently nonsensical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\P{\mathscr P}$
$\def\-{\setminus}$

First note that $\P(A : B)$ and $\P(A \- B)$ are both subsets of $\P(A)$.

Let $X \in \P(A)$. Then:
\begin{align*}
X \in \P(A \- B) & \iff X \subseteq A \- B \\
 & \iff X \subseteq A \text{ and } X \cap B = \emptyset \\
 & \iff X \subseteq A \text{ and } B \subseteq A \- X \\
 & \iff X \in \P(A : B).
\end{align*}

However, in general, if you don't succeed in writing an "equivalence proof" like this, the simplest way is to write two "implication proofs". As human beings we are much more used to reasoning by implications than to reasoning by equivalences.

Reasoning by implications means that you don't need any fancy formal symbol like " $\iff$ " and you can reason using only words like "hence", "thus", "it follows that", "we can see that", "we can conclude that", etc.

So I suggest you try to write the proof in two parts, going like this:

> First part. Let $X \in \P(A : B)$. Then: ... Blah blah blah. Thus $X \in \P(A \- B)$.
>
> We have proven that for any $X \in \P(A : B)$ we have $X \in \P(A \- B)$; thus we can conclude that $\P(A : B) \subseteq \P(A \- B)$.
>
> Second part. Let $X \in \P(A \- B)$. Then: ... Blah blah blah. Thus $X \in \P(A : B)$.
>
> We have proven that for any $X \in \P(A \- B)$ we have $X \in \P(A : B)$; thus we can conclude that $\P(A \- B) \subseteq \P(A : B)$.
>
> Conclusion. We have proven that both $\P(A : B) \subseteq \P(A \- B)$ and $\P(A \- B) \subseteq \P(A : B)$. Thus we can conclude that $\P(A : B) = \P(A \- B)$.